# Understanding the FutureWarning on using join_axes when concatenating with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
df1:

    A   B   C
1   A1  B1  C1
2   A2  B2  C2

df2:

    B   C   D
3   B3  C3  D3
4   B4  C4  D4
```

Columns B and C are identical for both.

I'd like to concatenate them vertically and keep the columns of the first DataFrame:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], join_axes=[df1.columns]):

    A   B   C
1   A1  B1  C1
2   A2  B2  C2
3   NaN B3  C3
4   NaN B4  C4
```

This works, but raises a

```
FutureWarning: The join_axes-keyword is deprecated. Use .reindex or .reindex_like on the result to achieve the same functionality.
```

I couldn't find (either in the documentation or through Google) how to "Use .reindex or .reindex_like on the result to achieve the same functionality".

Colab notebook illustrating issue: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13EBq2z0Nh05JY7ovrdnLGtfeqdKVvZq0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like what the error mentioned add `reindex`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns)])
Out[286]: 
     A   B   C
1   A1  B1  C1
2   A2  B2  C2
3  NaN  B3  C3
4  NaN  B4  C4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C1', 'C2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B3', 'B4'], 'C': ['C3', 'C4'], 'D': ['D1', 'D2']})

pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)[df1.columns]
```

yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

OR...

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     A   B   C
1   A1  B1  C1
2   A2  B2  C2
3  NaN  B3  C3
4  NaN  B4  C4
```